# Merge two list and discarding duplicates

Tags: python, algorithm, python-3.x, mergesort

I am trying to implement a function that merges two ordered lists into a third (ordered) one, but duplicates have to be discarded (basically the last step of a mergesort).

I think that this code can be generalized to an arbitrary number or lists, by keeping a list of indices, rather than 2 explicit ones.

```
def merge_no_duplicates(list_1, list_2):
    i = j = 0
    import collections
    result = collections.deque()

    while i < len(list_1) and j < len(list_2):
        if len(result) > 1 and list_1[i] == result[-1]:
            i += 1
            continue
        if len(result) > 1 and list_2[j] == result[-1]:
            j += 1
            continue

        if list_1[i] <= list_2[j]:

            result.append(list_1[i])
            i += 1
        elif list_2[j] < list_1[i]:
            result.append(list_2[j])
            j += 1

    # we still need to consume part of list_2
    if i == len(list_1):
        while j < len(list_2):

            if list_2[j] == result[-1]:
                j += 1
                continue 

            result.append(list_2[j])
            j += 1

    # still need to consume part of list_1
    if j == len(list_2):
        while i < len(list_1):

            if list_1[i] == result[-1]:
                i += 1
                continue 

            result.append(list_1[i])
            i += 1
    return result
```

Possible improvements: factor out the repetitive parts, for example by using something similar to this helper function:

```
check_duplicates(my_list, index):
    if my_list[index] == result[-1]:
        index += 1
```

Unfortunately this won't work (`index` is a parameter, and will not influence the behavior of `i` or `j`). Is this possible at all?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Pick a good return type**

A deque is a **D**ouble **E**nded **QUE**ue. Deques are great for when you have to insert and erase from the front as well as the back. You never need this for your problem - all you ever need is to insert at the end. You just need a normal list.

**Generate when you can**

Rather than necessarily giving the entire result all at once, it's better to just `yield` the next element as you go. This is a simple change in your algorithm (just `yield x` instead of `result.append(x)`), but could have serious performance implications down the line if you have lots of large iterables. If the caller wants a full list, then can always explicitly write `list(merge_no_duplicates(a, b, c))`.

**Use the standard when you can**

There is a function that already merges sorted inputs into a single sorted output: [`heapq.merge`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/heapq.html#heapq.merge). It *will* give you duplicates, but that seems like a much better starting point than writing everything from scratch:

```
def merge_no_duplicates(*iterables):
    last = object()

    for val in heapq.merge(*iterables):
        if val != last:
            last = val
            yield val
```

If you don't want to use `heapq.merge`, then you can at least use this framework to separate the "merge sorted iterables" concern from the "remove duplicates" concern.

Comment: Why is `merge_no_duplicates` a class? Can't it be just a function?

Comment: @Caridorc Yeah, it can.

Comment: regarding the deque: it seems that they should be faster than regular lists even if used only to append on the right: https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.deque

Comment: @meto Where do you see that in the linked doc?

Comment: @meto Running a quick `%%timeit` test in ipython, I got lists to be about 20% faster than deques for only-right-appends.

Comment: Then I must be wrong. I seem to remember that in a talk (I think by Raymond Hettinger) deques were said to be faster. Thanks for checking!

Comment: heapq.merge will lead to O(n log n) complexity instead of linear, right?

Comment: @ArekBulski No? Merging sorted iterables is linear.

Answer (score 3):

### Code refactor suggestion

A possible better approach would be to use something along the lines of:

- Let method accept a list of lists
- Create iterators for each of list
- Repeat following until no more elements:

  - Compare current element of all list

    - Push minimum to result list, iterate this list
    - Remove duplicates if any, and iterate corresponding list
- Return the resulting list

This should do the trick rather efficiently as well as elegantly. Will possibly code it later on, but just now I'm a little busy. But just thought I would give you something to think about regarding how to improve it.

***Update:** No need to reinvent the wheel, so please do use (and/or accept) code example provided by Barry. Will maybe code it just for the exercise, but most likely using heapq.merge, or some union-variant, will be a better implementation.*

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes the code to do what you want is already there. If you think about what is *like* a list and supports the operation you want to perform.

Convert both lists to sets, use union(), then convert back to a list. I think the sorted() is redundant BTW:

```
def merge_no_duplicates(iterable_1, iterable_2):
    myset = set(iterable_1).union(set(iterable_2))
    return sorted(list(myset))

list1 = [0, 2, 6, 'dup']
list2 = [9, 1, 3, 6, 7, 'dup']

print("Sorted union as list =", merge_no_duplicates(list1, list2))
```

Comment: `sorted` is certainly not redundant, since `set` is not sorted. Also, because of the sort, this is `O(n log(n))`, while the OP's code is `O(n)`

Comment: The reason I think it is redundant is that I have only observed union() returning sets that are sorted. The documentation does not indicate this is guaranteed however.

Comment: set are not sorted. what you observed is a coincidence, linked to the fact that small integers tend to be inserted in ordered buckets. Example, on my machine right now `set([1,2,3])` (appears to be ordered) but `set([1, 1000])` prints `{1000, 1}`. Result may differ from an environment to the other.

Comment: Also even with `sorted` that means these results only return in sorted order, not the original order that the lists were in.

Answer (score 2):

Hmmm, objects in an ordered list....  Are we overthinking?

```
def combine_remove_and_sort(list1, list2):
    return sorted(list(set(list1+list2)))
```

Kinda lazy but saves time for the really complex problems.

Comment: "Saves time"?  In what sense, lazyness when writing? Not in performance time if we're talking about lists of a non trivial small size.